# SQL: line 5:5: Column 'c' is ambiguous

Tags: sql, join, hiveql

I write such code in hiveql.

```
SELECT
    ttt1.rid,
    a,
    s,
    ttt2.num
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT
                rid,
                r ['a'] AS a,
                r ['s'] AS s
            FROM
                l
            WHERE
                dt BETWEEN '20210914'
                AND '20210917'
                AND r ['act'] = 3
                AND r ['pos'] = 1
                AND r ['s'] = 50011
                AND r ['c'] = 'anti'
        ) ttt1
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                r ['a'] AS a,
                r ['s'] AS s,
                count(1) AS num
            FROM
                l
            WHERE
                dt BETWEEN '20210914'
                AND '20210917'
                AND r ['act'] = 3
                AND r ['pos'] = 1
                AND r ['s'] = 50011
                AND r ['c'] = 'anti'
            GROUP BY
                r ['s'],
                r ['a']
        ) ttt2 ON (
            ttt1.a = ttt2.a
            AND ttt1.s = ttt2.s
        )
    )
```

I am wondering why it got ambiguous err.

> line 5:5: Column 'c' is ambiguous

CUZ `a` and `s` are the `join` keys for these two tables, it could ignore the `<TABLE_NAME>` before `<COLUMN_NAME>`.
Could anyone give me some explaination?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i reckon the problem is in the final select, you have not specified from which tables the a and s is to be selected from

```
SELECT
    ttt1.rid,
    a, --change this to ttt1.a
    s, --change this to ttt1.s 
    ttt2.num
```

Comment: but I think it is an `inner join`, so why have to use `<TALBE_NAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>` like `ttt1.a` not just use `<COLUMN_NAME>` like `a` so that I can ignore `<TABLE_NAME>`? CUZ I remember in some grammar restricted `<TABLE_NAME>` part could be ignored?